# Loop through JS Object and function on each item

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I must be over thinking the solution for this problem but can't seem to get this right.

I have an array `object` like so:

```
[ 
  {  ItemID: 1,  Path: '/Admin',     Name: 'Admin'   },
  {  ItemID: 2,  Path: '/Product',   Name: 'Product' },
  {  ItemID: 1,  Path: '/Reports',   Name: 'Reports' } 
]
```

I want to map over each item and for each one I need to run a function that will return whether they have access. i.e. a boolean (yes/no).

So far I have something like this:

```
const newData = data.map((curr, val , arr) => {

    if (checkAccess(username, curr.Name )) {  //checkAccess returns true or false
        return { ...current };
    }
});
```

I only want to return the ones they have access to.

so assuming that a user is unable to access `Admin` the final object should be:

```
[ 
  {  ItemID: 2,  Path: '/Product',   Name: 'Product' },
  {  ItemID: 1,  Path: '/Reports',   Name: 'Reports' } 
]
```

EDIT:

The issue is also that the function isn't returning a true / false

```
function checkInGroup(username, name) {
    let inGroup = "";
    ad.isUserMemberOf(username, name, function(err, isMember) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json("Error ", err);
        }
        inGroup = isMember; //this part returns true
    });
    return inGroup; //this seems to return empty string
}
```

Comment: You need to use .filter instead of .map

Comment: See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), as it creates a new array with all elements that pass the condition:

```
const res = data.filter(obj => obj.Path !== '/Admin');
console.log(res);
```